# Replace <p> with <p class="myClass">

Tags: templating, string, replace

Currently I am using twig's replace filter to replace the tags:

```
{% set str = block.body | raw %}
{{ str | replace('<p>', '<p class="myClass" data-wow-duration="1s">') }}
```

But on output it's not outputting the actual tags but:

```
&lt;p class=&quot;myClass&quot; data-wow-duration=&quot;1s&quot;&gt;
```

How do I keep the tags as tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `raw` filter on the replaced string (output), not `block.body` (input):

```
{% set str = block.body %}
{{ str | replace('<p>', '<p class="myClass" data-wow-duration="1s">') | raw }}
```

Also, some friendly advice: I'd like to point out that rewriting HTML in this way is [pretty risky](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).

*Shameless plug alert*, but I wrote a plugin called [Retcon HTML](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) which lets you manipulate your HTML content using PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) – a far safer approach :)

This is how you could achieve your specific goal using Retcon's [Attr method](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft/wiki/Attr):

```
{{ block.body | retconAttr( 'p', { 'class' : 'myClass', 'data-wow-duration' : '1s' } ) }}
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was something like this. Thank you! Final solution: 
`{{ block.body | retconAttr( 'p', { 'class' : 'myClass anotherClass', 'data-wow-duration' : '1' } ) }}`

Comment: No worries, happy it could help you out!